# Is there a module/way to send an email quarterly to a list of people about all the new content that has been published since the last email?

Tags: emails

I need to be able to take all the users who sign up for updates on a webform and on an editable frequency email them the new content (that I choose to send them) that has been published since the last email. Do any of y'all know if there is a module/way currently that I can do that? And if not what the best way to do that would be?

As an example, how would I send all the people from this webform results list a quarterly email informing them of all the blog posts that have been published since the last quarter?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question so this will be a broad answer.

> how would I send all the people from this webform results list a quarterly email informing them of all the blog posts that have been published since the last quarter?

First, how to get a list of all blog posts that have been published since the last quarter?  This can be done with the Views module; it's quite easy to generate a filtered list of content.

How to send the email?  Well, I wouldn't use Webform for this; I would use [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) instead.  This is by far the most popular Drupal module for mailing lists, and offers the great advantage of being open source, so you don't have to pay Mailchimp or another company for your newsletter.  The disadvantage is that it is not super easy to set up.